# Resolve linked path

Tags: android

I have a music player app which gets data from the media scanner (song name, artist name, etc.). Unfortunately quite a lot of devices have linked folders to their sdcard.
So my problem is for example: `/sdcard/music`, `/sdcard0/music` and `legacy/music` point to the same folder, but in the media scanner only one of those is listed.

Is there a way to resolve the links (or another workaround)?